# Treating Word Embeddings as Multivariate Gaussian Random Variables

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, natural-language

Suppose I want to specify some probabilistic clustering model (such as a mixture model or lda) over words, and instead of using the traditional method of representing words as an indicator vector $z$, where $z \sim \text{discrete}(\pi)$, I want to use the corresponding word embeddings extracted from word2vec, glove, etc. as input.

Is it fine for me to specify, say, a gaussian distribution for the word vectors, $x \sim \text{Normal}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, even if the true data generating process for these embeddings is not from a gaussian?  Furthermore, if I were to run this generative model forward and obtain a sample of $x$, how would I determine what word $x$ would represent?  That is, would I just take the word whose embedding was closest (using some distance metric) to $x$?

Comment: Can Central Limit Theorem help here? (Wanted to comment but couldn't due to limited reputation)

Comment: I know it is an old old question, but any chance you finally ended up with a solution here? I could not find any reasonable account about whether using normal generation + Euclidean distance in embedding spaces, even simple ones as word2vec or GloVe, has theoretical fundations.

Comment: For instance, should one use a specific variance-covariance matrix for generation, i.e., should one correct for privileged directions of the embedding space or on the contrary should one "go with it" ? Why are people using scaled dot product (aka cosine similarity) instead of Euclidean distance? How does this comes from the learning objective? So many questions ...